# Why Don't My Queried ID and Returned ID match?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm working on developing an application for my company, and I've been using Laravel. I needed a self-referencing BelongsToMany relationship on my user model to allow users to belong to other users. (ie AEs - Clients)

Here is my code:

```
$id = 6;
var_dump( "ID Queried Is: $id.", Sentry::getUser()->clients()->find($id)->toArray() );
```

The result of `Sentry::getUser()->clients()->find($id)` causes problems because when I use relationships, it uses the wrong ID to search through the related table.

I can use `Sentry::getUser()->clients->find($id)` and it returns a User with the ID specified, but I can't eager load any relations to that model (that I'm aware of).

[image: ID Queried and ID Returned Don't Match]

Does a BelongsToMany relationship (eg `Sentry::getUser()->clients()`) query the result set by the Primary Key on the pivot table rather than by the named key (`client_id`), and if so, how can I get around it?

Comment: Do you try to find client with id 6 or clients for user who has id 6 ?

Comment: I'm looking to find the Client who has ID #6, but only if the supposed user has client #6 in their clients. (the former)

Comment: For now, I'm using `Sentry::getUser()->clients()->with("folders")->where("client_id", "=", $id)->first()` as a workaround, but that feels so heavyhanded.

Comment: Maybe is the array structure, which starts from 0.

Comment: Is sentry looking at two different joined models? As in is `Sentry::getUser()->clients()` grabbing the id from getUser() rather than from clients()? id is actually the value from a Sentry model and not from your joined clients model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of this `Sentry::getUser()->clients()->find($id)` is, as you can see, pretty much correct. By that I mean it fetches correct user, however it `select *` so `id` (and possibly other common fields) is overriden, so the result has

```
$client->id; // id of the pivot table
```

while other fields are right.

So you can either query the relation like this:

```
$client = Sentry::getUser()->clients()->select('users.*')->find($id);
```

or lazy load the relation (if you really need this) and use `Collection` `find()` method:

```
$user = Sentry::getUser()->load('clients');
$client = $user->clients->find($id);

// or one line, not recommended:
$client = Sentry::getUser()->load('clients')->clients->find($id);
```

Otherwise just use what you tried:

```
$client = Sentry::getUser()->clients->find($id);
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of *why* id is using the id of the pivot table's row rather than the id of the user table's row. On a side note, does Laravel Eager load its relations by default? I thought they were lazy loaded (eg. not loaded until needed) by default, but you're examples above make me wonder whether it is or not.

Comment: No, it doesn't eager load anything unless you tell it to. What made you think it did?

Comment: `$user = Sentry::getUser()->load('clients');` and then prefacing that with 'or lazy load the relation (if you really need this)'. That made me wonder if Laravel Eager loads by default.

Comment: I said that because it seems, what you really wanted, was just a single client. That said, you don't need to load them all. Now, this is eager loading: `User::with('relation')->find/get()`, this is lazy loading: `$user->load('relation')/$users->load('relation')` (latter is loading on the collection, and here is automatic lazy loading done thanks to dynamic properties of Eloquent: `$user = User::find($id); $user->relation; // here it is loaded`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with this but I don't know if it will work for you and if it's what you want to achieve:

```
$users = Sentry::getUser()->with(array('clients' => function($q) use($id)
{
    $q->whereId($id);

}))->get()->toArray();
```